# Add a condition to directory NTFS permission using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory, ntfs

I want to use PowerShell to add a condition to a folder's NTFS permission. Is this possible with PowerShell?

I googled, but could not find anything. I've no problem creating a script to add or remove rules from folder ACL.

Here is a function I created, but would like to add a condition to the ACL:

```
    function AssignArchivePermissions($path){

    $NTGroup="SG-ServerOperators"
    $FileSystemRights="Modify"
    $InheritanceFlags="ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
    $PropagationFlags="None"
    $AccessControlType="Allow"

    $DenyGroup="CDIR-DenyDelete"
    $acl = (get-item $path ).GetAccessControl('Access')

    $aclst = $acl.Access

    foreach($identity in  $aclst.IdentityReference){
         if($identity.Value -eq "domainname\$DenyGroup"){
            $oldrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domainname\$DenyGroup", $aclst.FileSystemRights,$aclst.InheritanceFlags,$aclst.PropagationFlags,$aclst.AccessControlType)
             write-host "`n`r`n`r Removing $DenyGroup from $path ACL...`n`r"
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($oldrule)
        }
    }

    try{
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domainname\$NTGroup",$FileSystemRights,$InheritanceFlags,$PropagationFlags,$AccessControlType)

        write-host "`n`r`n`r Adding $NTGroup to $path ACL...`n`r"

        $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

        Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl

    }
    catch{}
}
```

Comment: I recommend googling it first

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.